# Счет вызовов onCreate в сервисе

Tags: android, service

У меня есть некий сервис, который что-то делает.

Но у него при закрытии главного активити второй раз вызывается `onCreate` и сервис перестает делать свою работу.

Чтобы устранить это - мне нужно сохранить некоторые данные в `SharedPreferences` и для этого нужно быть уверенным что сейчас не первый запуск `onCreate`, но я не знаю как это сделать.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевесьте выполнение работы сервиса на OnResume(). 
Ну или записывайте данные в SharedPreferences и удаляйте их оттуда при выходе из приложения. Сам класс с преференсами:

```
public class UserPreferences {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static UserPreferences userPreferences;
public static UserPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
    if (userPreferences == null) {
        userPreferences = new UserPreferences(context);
    }
    return userPreferences;
}

private UserPreferences(Context context){
sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedSettings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public void storeUserInfo(String userCity){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("storeUserInfo", userCity);
    editor.commit();
}
public String getUserInfo(){
    return sharedPreferences.getString("storeUserInfo", null);
}
public void clearShared(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Вызывать так:

```
UserPreferences userPreferences = userPreferences.getInstance(getActivity());
userPreferences.getInstance(getActivity()).storeUserInfo("SomeInfo").
```

Если не хотите использовать строку в преференс, то можно воспользоваться методом putInt(). Далее все зависит от пожеланий. 
Более [детально](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html?hl=ru) про жизненный цикл приложения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Но мне нужен не преференс(с ним я уже разобрался, кстати можно не усложнять себе жизнь выделяя целый класс) мне нужно узнать какой сейчас запуск onCreate. Первый или второй. Вот и все. Я гуглил этот вопрос и не нашел ответа поэтому написал сюда.

Comment: Запуск OnCreate() всегда один, он может быть вызван из разных состояний приложения. Почитайте более детально про управление жизненным циклом приложения. Ссылку прикрепил к ответу

Comment: Ты скажи это моему сервису, у которого их два: первый при нажатии кнопки Старт, а вторая при закрытие активити.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите в сервисе статическую boolean переменную. В оnCreate проверяйте её значение. Если она false- это первый запуск. Иначе- следующий. После пооверки установите ей значение true